# JavaScript array id loop

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, loops

I am quite new to JavaScript professionally and I have encountered a situation where I need to give every item in a JavaScript array a unique id.

The array is very large so it cannot be done manually. Is there a simple way to do this? A simple numerical id for each would be superb. It is so that a PHP developer can easily manipulate the array and this is how he has requested it be done.

Comment: They index of each element in the array is a unique numerical id

Comment: Can you give more context? In a sense, the item's index in the array could serve as an id. But it depends on what the real intent here is.

Comment: What does your array look like?

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in JS do have unique IDs - its index value.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of doing so:

Functional

```
array = /* Long or dynamically sized array of objects */

array.forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.uuid = index;
};
```

Iterative

```
array = /* Long or dynamically sized array of objects */

for (var ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
  array[ix].uuid = ix;
}
```

The index of the element of the array is being used as the UUID, since I'm not sure how you are generating the UUIDs, and that is the simplest.  f you are sending the entire array through the server, you don't need a UUID based on index.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your quick responses, I will experiment with these ideas in a few moments. Context wise, the project is a fairly simple game and the array is used to try the tile based game board. Each tile will need to be manipulated by the backend developer in one way or another. Here is how I am constructing the array:                                                                                                                               for (var row = startRow; row < rowCount; row++) {
                           for (var col = startCol; col < colCount; col++) {//loop}