# How to supply unique ids to elements within a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, 2d

I'm fairly new to javascript professionally and I've encountered a situation where I need to supply unique ids to every element in a 2D array programmatically. I asked this question before but I made the mistake of not specifying how the array is structured and received an answer appropriate to a 1d array. My array is structured as follows and it would be great to know how to create unique ids for every element within the array:

```
 var startRow = Math.floor(scroll.x / alpha.width);
                   var startCol = Math.floor(scroll.y / alpha.height);
                   var rowCount = startRow + Math.floor(canvas.width / alpha.width) + 2;
                   var colCount = startCol + Math.floor(canvas.height / alpha.height) + 2;

                   rowCount = ((startRow + rowCount) > grid.width) ? grid.width : rowCount;
                   colCount = ((startCol + colCount) > grid.height) ? grid.height : colCount;


                   for (var row = startRow; row < rowCount; row++) {
                       for (var col = startCol; col < colCount; col++) {
                           var tilePositionX = alpha.width * row - 25;
                           var tilePositionY = alpha.height * col + 45;
```

Many thanks

Also, here is the previous response I received: [JavaScript array id loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992604/javascript-array-id-loop/8992668#8992668)

Comment: There are no arrays in the code you supplied (no one-dimensional arrays or two-dimensional arrays). Where do you want the ids to be set?

Comment: @BenLee - looks like (s)he's programmatically creating the array (rowCount, colCount etc) :)

Answer (score 0):

Like your last question said, why don't you just refer to the index - it's totally unique. A 2D array would have `[i][j]` indices, which can't be occupied by more than one item.

```
var startRow = 0;
var startCol = 0;
var rowCount = 10;
var colCount = 5;
var someArray = [];

for (var row = startRow; row < rowCount; row++) {
   someArray[row] = [];
   for (var col = startCol; col < colCount; col++) {
       someArray[row][col] = row + ' ' + col;
   }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, the array is called tileMap and is setup as var tileMap = []; I have had some success with Havvy's iterative solution: for (var ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++) {
  array[ix].uuid = ix;
}
 but I'm not sure how to get it to work based on row and col

Comment: I'm confused why you need to store the contents of the array in another array. What's the purpose of the whole array in general?

Comment: thank you for your time Aram, the array is used to draw a tile based gameboard on a html5 canvas so the structure of the array is being used to draw a 2D gameboard in the browser window. The reason for the id is so that the colour of particular tiles (cells in the array) can be altered by reading in a colour value from the database.

Comment: In that case I would make a method that received the tile (i,j) coordinates and a colour, and applied this colour to the tile if it existed. If colour is all you are storing, then it can be in the form of a HEX colour string.